# Find/Access other ToolWindowPanes in Visual Studio from another ToolWindowPane?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility, vspackage

Is there any way to find all or one specific Visual Studio ToolWindowPane, e.g. I have one ToolWindowPane that needs to get ahold of one particular other ToolWindowPane (if loaded/available).

Is this doable, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Package.FindToolWindow(Type type,int ID,bool create)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package.findtoolwindow%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), where ID is "number" of tool window (if it has more than one instance).